# Send string from one activity to another and use it as url parameter in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-cloud-messaging

Is anybody knows how to use string received from one activity in another activity which have AsyncTask and use this string as a part of url link in doInBackground? I need to start activity which showing feeds when a GCM notification arrives and use string from notifications to start activity. Here is activity which sends string (GcmIntentServices) and activity with AsyncTask which receive string and forward to AsyncTask to build url link for feed. String is msg1 and it consist of text which has to be append to url link in AsyncTask.

GcmIntentServices.java:

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private static final String TAG = "GcmIntentService";
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    Context context;
    public static final int notifyID = 9001;
    String msg1;
    String msg2;

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        String msg1 = intent.getStringExtra("cat_name");
        String msg2 = intent.getStringExtra("message");

        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            /*
             * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM
             * will be extended in the future with new message types, just ignore
             * any message types you're not interested in, or that you don't
             * recognize.
             */
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                        extras.toString());
            // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i+1)
                            + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                // Post notification of received message.
            //    sendNotification(extras.getString("Notice"));
                sendNotification(msg1);
                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String msg1) {

     /*   Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, AndroidRssReader.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra("message", msg);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);  */

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, AndroidRssReader.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
    //    b.putString("message", msg);
        b.putString("cat_name", msg1);
    //    resultIntent.putExtra("cat_name", msg1);
        resultIntent.putExtras(b);
        resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
           //     .setContentTitle("Alert")
          //      .setContentText("You've received new message.")
                .setContentTitle("")
                .setContentText(msg1)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg1))
                         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gcm_cloud);
        // Set pending intent
        mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        // Set Vibrate, Sound and Light
        int defaults = 0;
        defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        mNotifyBuilder.setDefaults(defaults);
        // Set the content for Notification
    //    mNotifyBuilder.setContentText("New message from Server");
        // Set autocancel
        mNotifyBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        // Post a notification
        mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
    }
    }
```

AndroidRssReader.java (UPDATED):

```
public class AndroidRssReader extends ListActivity {

    private RSSFeed myRssFeed = null;

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private String kat;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainrss);


        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if(extras != null) {
            if(extras.containsKey("cat_name")) {

                String kat = extras.getString("cat_name");

                MyTask task = new MyTask();

                task.execute(kat);

                Toast.makeText(AndroidRssReader.this, kat, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  // here I'm getting kat value properly!!!

            }
        }

    }



    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{


        @Override

        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

            String kat = params[0];

            Log.d("AJDE!", kat); // here, I'm getting kat value properly in logcat, why kat doesnt go toURL rssUrl ???

            try {

                URL rssUrl = new URL("http://www.example.com/category/" + kat + "/feed/");

                SAXParserFactory mySAXParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser mySAXParser = mySAXParserFactory.newSAXParser();
                XMLReader myXMLReader = mySAXParser.getXMLReader();
                RSSHandler myRSSHandler = new RSSHandler();
                myXMLReader.setContentHandler(myRSSHandler);
                InputSource myInputSource = new InputSource(rssUrl.openStream());
                myXMLReader.parse(myInputSource);

                myRssFeed = myRSSHandler.getFeed();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            if (myRssFeed!=null)
            {
                TextView feedTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.feedtitle);
                TextView feedSadrzajPosta = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.feedsadrzaj_posta);
                TextView feedPubdate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.feedpubdate);
                TextView feedLink = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.feedlink);
                feedTitle.setText(myRssFeed.getTitle());
                feedSadrzajPosta.setText(myRssFeed.getSadrzajPosta());
                feedPubdate.setText(myRssFeed.getPubdate());
                feedLink.setText(myRssFeed.getLink());

                ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> adapter =
                        new ArrayAdapter<RSSItem>(getApplicationContext(),
                                R.layout.list_black_text,R.id.list_content,myRssFeed.getList());
                setListAdapter(adapter);

                //      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GGG: " + msg1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }else{



                TextView textEmpty = (TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
                textEmpty.setText("No Feed Found!");
            }

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

     /*   @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(AndroidRssReader.this, "Please WAIT", "Loading ...");
        }  */

    }



    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,ShowDetails.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("keyTitle", myRssFeed.getItem(position).getTitle());
        bundle.putString("keySadrzajPosta", myRssFeed.getItem(position).getSadrzaj_posta());
        bundle.putString("keyLink", myRssFeed.getItem(position).getLink());
        bundle.putString("keyPubdate", myRssFeed.getItem(position).getPubdate());
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Now, I'm getting String kat with expected value, checked with Log.d in doInbackground, but string kat doesnt go further and use in URL link.

Comment: Issue is you declare msg1 many times
  String msg1; . First change the variable name. Then only we can check where is the error

Comment: I changed the name of variables, still not working

Comment: Can you update code now after changing the variable names and codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to generate the url in a string apart and show the output of logcat ? eg

```
String url = "http://www.example.com/category/"+kat+"/feed/";
Log.i("URL",url);
```

so we can know better what happens

Comment: Its worked, finally, it was problem with generating URL in doInBackground. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you must send the string as a parameter msg1

```
task.execute(msg1);
```

doInBackground then receives follows

```
String msg1 = arg0[0];
```

then you can use the variable perfectly msg1

Comment: I tried your way many times before, not working! I'm start to believe that is cannot be done!